# Can we visually identify a fleet from Earth with modern technology?

Tags: internal-consistency, spaceships, space-warfare

Two fleets from opposing factions are approaching each other at sublight speed at the edge of our Solar System. The Earth is in a position to affect the outcome of the battle, (i.e, superweapon, etc.) but must correctly identify the fleet friendly to them. Unfortunately, **Earth is temporarily unable to identify them by any means other than visually.** That means we cannot send a hail to the friendly fleet, nor can we send a scout or fleet of our own to confirm at close range. By the time Earth is able to get these capabilities back online, the battle will already be decided.

**Would we be able to identify the allied fleet, and if so, to what granularity?**

Could we distinguish between something such as this:
[image]
[image]

Or this, where the design methodologies would look very similar from afar? Or would it take two entirely different ones, like UNSC designs vs Borg style cubes? Would we be able to differentiate between fleets that share the **same class** of ship, but have different insignia stenciled on them, i.e, a large rebel flag or imperial flag?

A few details to hammer out first:

**The viewing conditions for both fleets are considered the same. One does not have sunlight shining on it while the other doesn't, for example.**

**Earth still has its modern day space telescopes (2018), but only ones within it's own orbit.**

**The opposing fleets are roughly the same size, as well as their individuals. So finding a standout such as an obviously distinct capital ship such as a Super Star Destroyer or Death Star style weapon is out of the question.**

**The baseline distance where both fleets start at and move roughly parallel to the Earth is about the distance of Neptune.**

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you are not asking if this can be done in principal but with contemporary telescopes? "Modern day" could mean today or whatever is state of the art in your scenario which is at least a couple of centuries in the future

Comment: I am asking in regards to 2018, modern technology.

Comment: Here you can find a picture of the very large moon Triton of Neptune as seen from Earth with contemporary equipment: http://solarviews.com/cap/nep/tritonhst.htm Imo the question should be how you even detect any fleet approaching

Comment: A further question I would have is, what level of resolution would we need to even have a chance of identifying the fleet?

Comment: Space is big. The Empire's Death Star would probably go unnoticed at that distance. Anything we saw would be 8 to 16 hours after the fact, and be mistaken for noise artifacts if seen at all, Any help we sent would arrive 20 years after the fact.

Comment: @pojo-guy Well, the basic assumption here is that they wont be able to engage each other for at least a few days, a week or two at most, and that the superweapon itself due to the power of technology/plot could begin IMMEDIATELY damaging the enemy to a high degree of accuracy.

Comment: Also, Military Strategy tells us that such tight fleet formations will not be used, precisely so they cannot be all destroyed by a single firing of your superweapon. Even modern navies keep their ships tens of miles apart, to avoid nukes, and get better coverage for both detection and weaponry.

Comment: @BaldBear You are correct. Although couldn't that be a strategy as well?  Say you leak that information to the enemy, so they spread out. The allied fleet stays compact, an obvious sign that they aren't trying to avoid the weapon because they know it won't be used against them. Something along those lines psychologically.

Comment: @Raznarok How do you aim the weapon? Since the battle is happening 8 to 16 light hours away, all you can see is where the ships were.  Assuming this super weapon is some sort of energy beam, and the trigger was pressed immediately (remember the entire fleet, at best, looks like noise in CCD), the weapon would strike the places where the target was 16 to 32 hours previously. In that time, the target will have moved at least in an orbital arc, and if maneuvering for a battle, he could be anywhere in a cone of action determined by the point he was spotted and his (unknown) ability to maneuver.

Comment: Its a case of the weapon being precursor technology level plot wise, with the operators being hilariously inferior. They barely know how to operate it let alone how it really works. Its the sort of sufficiently advanced technology indistinguishable from magic kind of situation. Simply designating a target off a few pixels is sufficient for it hit with a high degree of accuracy. It could have some sort of FTL tracking system but the humans have no idea. The plot point being that they have this insanely OP weapon that they're desperately trying to leverage using 'Real' technology.

Comment: @Raznarok To function, the weapon needs to either be precognitive or have both FTL sensors and "business end", which puts it outside of reality. This "precursor" type technology might as well be magic.

Comment: @pojo-guy For the humans it basically is magic. Most of the features of the weapon are obfuscated by its design, passwords, etc. The alien situation hasn't given them enough time to find out enough about it. It can have whatever solution that would make sense, but the real important part is that the humans haven't the slightest idea at the moment. If they had access to the full targeting suite it would be advanced enough to make their satellites pointless, but it's not something they can access, so they basically have to do everything backwards.

Answer (score 6):

**Nope.** Read [this answer to *What is the resolution in megapixels of the Hubble Telescope?* on Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18101/525)
For Hubble space telescope, the entire dwarf planet of Pluto is 2*2 pixels.

Hubble is not cutting edge anymore, though. That honor belong to adaptive optics, e.g. the [Very Large Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Telescope)
The best resolution is 0.001 arc-second, and Pluto is 0.1 arcsec, so we have 100 pixels for a Pluto, which is 1400 miles in diameter, so you have **14 miles per pixel**.

You might be able to tell the color of a really large ship, or count the number of large ships if they are far apart, but that's about it.

Comment: A further question I would have is, what level of resolution would we need to even have a chance of identifying the fleet?

Comment: So it would need to be an enormous capital class slugfest or the battle would have to be closer to the Earth to even have the vaguest idea then.

Comment: @Raznarok, "enormous" is a wholly inadequate word in this case.  The capital ships would need to be about half the diameter of Pluto, 750 miles, just to get 50-100 pixels.  I remember the good old days of computer games.  There's not much you can identify with 100 pixels.

Comment: Hi Bald Bear. I added some clarification to your links. By all means feel free to [Edit] further.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about insignia. But if we know about ships' design, we could be able to differentiate them.

The idea is that when approaching the inner solar system, and likely even before that, ships will fire their engines for braking down and maneuvering. This is the most likely how they are going to be discovered, by the way. If two fleets' engines are different, we can analyze the exhaust spectrum and determine whether it's a friend of foe.

P.S. This answer assumes that ships use "scientifically plausible" reaction engines.

Comment: Would we be able to analyze the exhaust spectrum from that distance though? I wouldn't doubt we could simply look at the ships themselves once they got close enough, although I think exhaust is an important part of the IFF.

Comment: @Raznarok I assume that incoming ships will need to do much more engine burning than our current interplanetary probes do. Engine exhaust will be much brighter than any reflected sunlight.

Comment: Seems more reasonable the more I think about it. Any capital class style ship is going to be putting out a LOT of exhaust to move that amount of mass, and there are dozens of them arriving within a few miles of each other.

Comment: @Raznarok There's no need to continually fire the engines, at least not with something resembling modern day reaction engines. Most space travel is done without any active propulsion. Typical propulsive maneuvering time is on the order of tens of minutes even for interplanetary missions within our solar system; the rest of the time is spent in freefall.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - this is when traveling at slow speeds, below or slightly above Sun's escape velocity. Interstellar fleet should be arriving at a speed orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: @Alexander Sure, but you still don't need to continually fire the engines. You just need to get up to speed, and then you can coast. Continually firing the engines means you are continually accellerating (along *some* vector), thereby changing your velocity vector. If you're trying to slow down that's what you'll do, but if our solar system is just a navigational obstacle (or a navigational reference point), then other factors seem likely to be more important.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling and the key question here is how long would it take to get "up to speed". If we are slowing down from 0.01c to near standstill at constant 1g, it will take a few days of continuous engine firing.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I get that part, I'm just not sure if a fleet of mile long ships going full thrust to accelerate to a reasonable speed for a 10 minute period is enough for us to notice. Would it be like the equivalent of cavitating in a submarine where our observers would be like "yep, that's X's fleet."

Comment: Given that the best resolution with modern optics is 14 miles per pixel, a 1 mile long ship would register, at best, as a single pixel. More likely, a fleet of them travelling close together would register as a single pixel. You can't differentiate be ship design.

Comment: @pojo-guy I'm afraid your are missing my point. We don't need to resolve ships. We need only to analyze the spectrum. One pixel is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If I read into the question properly, we know nothing about either fleet.

Then technically, neither fleet are our allies.

Odds are that whichever fleet we shot down, the other fleet would BECOME our allies quite quickly.

As for identifying who the "good guys" are, about the only thing I could imagine is possibly looking at **combat tactics**.  Especially brutal tactics, as opposed to surgical strikes intended to incapacitate might suggest a more brutal (and possibly "evil" society.

Comment: We do know what their ships look like, but its more of a question of can we identify them from this distance. Sort of how it can become difficult to differentiate between allied and axis tanks through smoke and chaos. Although picking arbitrarily could be in our best interest as you said.

Comment: Slavers would presumably aim for minimal loss of life, anyone fighting forces that never ever surrender might adopt extermination tactics. Though if one side expects Earth's support they probably would be more inclined to stall and maintain separation.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, optical identification of the fleets is effectively impossible unless we postulate improbably large space telescopes, with mirrors measured in kilometres rather than metres.

However, visual identification of targets isn't the only way to go, and even visual identification might be useful if we are looking at something else.

Space is both a vacuum and extremely cold, so the heat energy of the spacecraft stands out like a beacon against the background of space, and isn't absorbed by intervening fluids (at least not on the scale of the solar system. There are interstellar nebula of gasses and dust which can absorb energy on a cosmic scale). This is the reason there is "no stealth" in space, the spacecraft are highly visible in the infrared spectrum.

This includes heat radiating from the ships even when they are drifting, since a great deal of "hotel" power in needed for life support, running the various ships systems and so on. Unless the aliens live in a cryogenic environment, the ships will have to be at several hundred degrees Kelvin just so the crews can survive.

The radiated energy of the ships is compounded when they use their engines. [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardetect.php#id--There_Ain't_No_Stealth_In_Space) points out that the Space Shuttle engines put out enough energy that the small manoeuvring thrusters could be theoretically detected out to the asteroid belt, and the burn of the SSME would be visible from the orbit of Neptune. More detail can be found [here](https://childrenofadeadearth.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/stealth-in-space/).

[image]

*Exhaust plume of an F-35*

So while the ships are still smaller than a single pixel, you will have a large and otherwise inexplicable infrared source in deep space. Assuming you have other information about the aliens, you might be able to determine who is who by carefully looking at the infrared signatures. One set of aliens might have significantly warmer or cooler spacecraft because of their environmental preferences, and the energy used to manoeuvre will be very distinctive, especially if you have information about the actual sizes/masses of the ships (larger ships will require more energy to move, so you have a metric of sorts to determine which fleet is which).

Other sensors are available as well. We use radar on Earth, and the Arecibo radio telescope has been used to do radar scans of Venus, providing surface details even from that distance. The sensitivity of the telescope was great enough that during the Cold War it was used for Electronic Intelligence (ELINT), analyzing Russian radars by *[gathering reflections from the Moon](https://infogalactic.com/info/Arecibo_Observatory#Other_uses)*! With this level of sensitivity, radar imaging of the fleets is also possible, but once again, you would have difficulty resolving individual ships.

[image]

*Arecibo radio telescope*

Even more exotic systems could be postulated using current technology. A satellite could be launched with a high powered laser to conduct [LIDAR](https://infogalactic.com/info/Lidar) scans of the fleets, to compliment optical, infrared and radar searches. This would likely be in support of fine tuning any observations, and aiming the hypothetical super weapon in the OP. [Neutrino detectors](https://infogalactic.com/info/Neutrino_detector) deep beneath the Earths surface could also be used to attempt to detect the neutrino emissions from the ships nuclear reactors, although this would be a very low resolution detector.

So although visual detection would not be possible or readable at this time, there are still multiple systems which could be used to locate and identify the various fleets.

Comment: Arecibo's major downside in this case is probably its restricted ability to scan the sky. The reflector is fixed, though the feed can presumably be moved (I haven't checked). A more movable feed could likely be built and installed, but you're still dealing with the very narrow beam width of the reflector at any reasonable frequency of interest. *And* you're assuming that whatever is out there is emitting RF in a frequency range that Arecibo, or any other similar equipment (FAST, for one) can reasonably receive. That may or may not be an accurate assumption.

Comment: I'm speaking of using Arecibo as an active radar emitter, but using it as an ELINT platform is likely more useful in this case. As a spherical reflector,  the Arecibo facility has the ability to scan a somewhat larger area than you might think, but it is still fixed, limiting the overall ability to scan.

Comment: @Thucydides So if we can detect the SSME from Neptune theoretically, then a fleet of a dozen plus Star Destroyer class vessels is going to be like firing a gun in a quiet library in terms of subtlety on the infared spectrum then?

Comment: Not a gun, but a cannon. A great big, Krupp K-5 railway cannon type cannon.....

Answer (score 1):

A massive fleet is the size of the pointy tip of a pin compared to a planet, much less the expanse of open space visible from the planet.  Bald Bear's answer is very important (I upvoted it).  If we knew *exactly* where to look (three dimensions!) we'd be hard pressed to see the fleet to recognize it before 4-5X the distance to our own moon.  And that might be an optimistic assumption.

Comment: A further question I would have is, what level of resolution would we need to even have a chance of identifying the fleet?

Comment: @Raznarok, Can you clarify your request?  The problem Bald Bear is talking about is that our resolution technology is good enough if the optics allow you to focus in closely enough (they can't) and you know *exactly* where to look.  If the question is, given let's ignore optics and view 180° in both polar planes, what would it take?  The answer is petapixels-per-arc° and that assumes the detector is sensitive enough and filtered enough to capture so little light amidst a field of so much.

Comment: Correct me if I interpreted this wrong, we would need either better optics, or an insanely high level of resolution to see the fleet? Is what you are saying?

Comment: @Raznarok, yes, and the consequence of better optics is that the further out the battle, the more you need to know ahead of time where to look.  Think of using binoculars.  An entire battle could be going on a mile to your left but you're admiring the bird a mile to the battle's right.  Better optics is good, better light detection is better (and the whomping large amount of processing power to go along with it to analyze the images).

Comment: Ok. So we would essentially need a near future-ish level of optics/technology to try and identify what would basically be pixel art fleets. Yeah, the assumption was that the humans knew to an extreme high degree of certainty where the fleets would arrive due to plot, etc.

Comment: @Raznarok, what keeps me up at night is that there could be space battles going on all the time *right now* and we wouldn't know about it unless we got very lucky.  Considering galactic time scales, space battles are instantaneous events, like a flash of lightning.  What would make more sense is a sphere of satellites at the orbit of Mars that detected the flashes and directed us to "look here."  That would require much less tech in terms of optics & detection resolution.  But, yes, for your plot, more tech than we have.

Comment: Ahh. Great points as usual, but is a Mars starting point close enough still?

Comment: @Raznarok, from the perspective of a story, Mars is believable.  In terms of reality, you'd likely need detecting spheres at the orbits of Mars and Saturn.  The problem is cost-vs-value, the further out you go, the more space you're trying to cover, and the more cost (in tech or # of satelites) is involved.

Comment: How did you arrive at the figure "4-5X the distance to our own moon" (which works out to about 1.5 to 2.0 million km, given that the moon's orbital radius around Earth is about 400,000 km)? I'm not saying you're right or wrong, I'm just curious why you think that particular distance is the right answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, An "it feels right" guess based on my own use of a telescope, the relative size of the moon, the estimated size of an incoming fleet.  I figured we could identify the fleet at 20% of what we could see at the distance of the noral moon.